# Capturing and copying created file in powershell

Tags: powershell

Im using this script to scan a folder for the created files. Sadly this are temp files and gets created and deleted by a program we use.

```
Code:
$folder = 'C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\RestBar\RestBar'
$filter = '*.*'                             # <-- set this according to your requirements
$destination = 'C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB'
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $true              # <-- set this according to your requirements
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
 $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
 $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
 $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
 Write-Host "The file '$name' at '$path'was $changeType at $timeStamp"
 Copy-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose # Force will overwrite files with same name
}
```

The Script its not being able to copy the file to the destination folder. Im assuming that the files gets deleted before it can be copied. Its there a way to lock the file so it dosent get deleted but after the copy operation?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are dealing with a race condition then there is no guarentee that you can intercept this fast enough _every time_. Shall I assume you have no control over how your "program" works? can you have it place files in some other location and you can put them back when you are done.

Comment: Does the copy sometimes work but not always?

Comment: Hi Matt.
No I dont have a control on how the program works. And no I dont get any data copied. 

My idea its to lock the file once it gets created so I can copy it. But I dont know how to do it...

Comment: Does the program _have to_ delete the file? You could remove its rights to delete files? If you can't copy it in time I don't see how you will have time to change security and change it back. You might be better of _moving_ the file as that should be faster and copy it back if the program needs it.

Comment: I really dont want to change the way the program works because I dont know what consecuences it might have

Comment: It seems  you have a difficult situation. Just to add to the considerations, would "Created" be indicated before the file is fully written? If "Created" was set when the program started writing the file, your script might not be able to read it until the writing is complete.

Comment: The creation of the file gets watched by the script. But not copied... so I need a way to lock it so I can do move it.

Comment: what's the name of the file that you cannot copy? is it a temp file (perhaps created with delete on close)?  is it a file that is already locked for exclusive access?  how do you know it's getting deleted before you can copy it?

Comment: when I start a process in the POS program it gets created. So that means that the file seems to be locked by the POS, once the POS program finishes the process it will delete the file.

Comment: Perhaps you can shadow copy the locked files? Not sure how you'd get the entire file if it is deleted as soon as your program is done with it. If you know of a point in time that the file is fully written, before it is deleted check [this site](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/6gf2pi/powershell_backup_script_that_deals_with_opened/) for some ideas on grabbing a shadow copy.

Comment: After a lot of testing this aproach will not work. So I will try another one.